# HP DL 360G7 and HP smartarray P410i RAID 1 troubleshooting

Tags: windows, hp, hp-proliant, ilo

This should be an old story, but it happened just couple weeks ago.
System is as in the topic, with two disks in RAID1, one day one of the disks fell off. I ordered new disks for future use and continued work.

Couple of days after a failure, I looked on HP ACU and I wasn't happy. It said:

*Code 730 146GB 1-Port SAS Drive at Port 1I: Box 1 Bay 2 is a part of a logical drive that is not supported by the current configuration. Any configuration command (e.g. logical drive creation, array expansion, etc.) or modification to the controller will result in the loss of all existing data on the disabled logical drive(s).*

Does that mean that on that "new" disk was something else? Was that owerwritten by a RAID rebuild?

Short after that (week and a half) second disk failed. I looked in the ILO and there was another information in Integrated Management Log:

*POST Error: 1786-Drive Array Recovery Needed 
POST Error: 1747-Slot X Drive Array - Unsupported Array Configuration Detected - More logical drive(s) configured than this controller model can support. All logical drive(s) have been disabled.*

What does that actually mean? System was not restarted since then.
I would be glad if someone explained. Guess it is time to change that ol' scrap, but ...**you know**. Beer is on me ;-)

edit:
heres the config:

```
    => controller all show config detail

    Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
       Bus Interface: PCI
       Slot: 0
       Serial Number: 5001438010F6B050
       RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
       Controller Status: OK
       Chassis Slot:
       Hardware Revision: Rev C
       Firmware Version: 3.66
       Rebuild Priority: Medium
       Expand Priority: Medium
       Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs
       Surface Scan Mode: Idle
       Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
       Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
       Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
       Cache Board Present: False
       Drive Write Cache: Disabled
       SATA NCQ Supported: True

    Array: A
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 0 MB
      Status: OK



  Logical Drive: 1
     Size: 136.7 GB
     Fault Tolerance: RAID 1
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 35132
     Strip Size: 256 KB
     Status: Recovering, 85% complete
     Unique Identifier: 600508B1001CB31FAB7C625ADD2A839B
     Disk Name: \\.\PhysicalDrive0
     Mount Points: Unknown 100 MB, C:\ 100.0 GB
     Logical Drive Label: A0020CBA5001438010F6B050AA69
     Mirror Group 0:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, Rebuilding)
     Mirror Group 1:
        physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:1
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 1
     Status: Rebuilding
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 146 GB
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPD2
     Serial Number:         PCVBYM3E
     Model: HP      DG0146FARVU
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0GBPS

  physicaldrive 1I:1:2
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 2
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 146 GB
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPD2
     Serial Number:         PCVENBPE
     Model: HP      DG0146FARVU
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0GBPS
  This physical drive is part of a logical drive that is not supported by the current configuration. Any configuration command (e.g. logical drive creation, array expansion, etc.) or modification to the controller will result in the loss of all existing data on the disabled logical drive(s).
```

=>

Comment: How many logical drives are configured? Can you post the array configuration?

Comment: @ewwhite edited question

Comment: Please post the full output of `ctrl all show config detail
`

Comment: @ewwhite there you go :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the error description here: http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/docs/iss/shared/gen9/error/Advanced/Content/247994.htm

I don't think it's a good use of time troubleshooting the specifics of your setup because the firmware on the controller and disks is so out of date.

Your Smart Array P410 is using firmware version 3.66 from from 2011 and your disks also need attention because they're on HPD2 from 2009. Where did you get this equipment?!?

Please update the firmware of all of your devices and ensure the cache module is healthy and has a battery/FBWC unit attached.

This product advisory from HP explains the situation in detail:
https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0105422

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I already got proliant servicepack, but do I need to worry about that "Any configuration command or modification to the controller will result in the loss of all existing data" after I perform update of the disk/controller firmware?

Comment: Your setup is old and out of date. Typically these are not intrusive updates... but I don't know how you got to this point or where this equipment was sourced, or how it went 10 years without updates.

Comment: Legacy, as i said it should be discarded long time ago. Nevertheless I will prepare for the update, and plan migration. Many thanks.

Comment: Vote accordingly. Let your server finish the rebuild first.